# How to get a list of available ActiveX on user system?

Tags: delphi, activex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to list all installed ActiveX controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755351/how-to-list-all-installed-activex-controls)

I want to get a full list of available activeX  controls on user system. Just like what delphi does when you want to import an activeX. (it shows a list)

Regards,
Javid

Comment: duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649171/how-to-list-all-activex-controls ?

Comment: I want to do this using Delphi. I want to do it with coding, not by external stuff.

Comment: It does appear to be a dupe, but of a different [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755351/). On the plus side, this does answer your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wrote myself. Just add `Registry` unit and you're finished!

```
procedure GetActiveXObjects(List: TStringList);
  procedure KeyNotFound;
  begin
    raise exception.create('Key not found.');
  end;
const
  PATH = 'Software\\Classes\\TypeLib\\';
var
  R: TRegistry;
  S1, S2: TStringList;
  S, Output: String;
begin
  List.Clear;
  try
    S1 := TStringList.Create;
    S2 := TStringList.Create;
    R := TRegistry.create(KEY_READ);
    R.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;

    if (not R.OpenKey(PATH, False)) then
      KeyNotFound;
    R.GetKeyNames(S1);
    for S in S1 do begin
      // Position: CLSID
      R.CloseKey;
      if (not R.OpenKeyReadOnly(PATH + S + '\\')) then
        Continue;
      R.GetKeyNames(S2);
      // Position:Version
      if (S2.Text = '') or (not R.OpenKeyReadOnly(S2.Strings[0])) then
        Continue;
      Output := R.ReadString('');
      if Output <> '' then
        List.Add(Output);
    end;

  finally
    R.Free;
    S1.Free;
    S2.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a c++ version of what you want (almost). You get a list of all classes. It guess that the ActiveX import wizard in Delphi has one row for each library.
[How to list all installed ActiveX controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755351/how-to-list-all-installed-activex-controls)

In Delphi you can do something like this.

```
const
    CATID_Control: TGUID  = '{40FC6ED4-2438-11cf-A3DB-080036F12502}';

procedure GetActiveXControlList(List: TStringList);
var
    catInfo: ICatInformation;
    enumGuid: IEnumGUID;
    ClassID: TGUID;
    Fetched: Cardinal;
    Name: PWideChar;
begin
    OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_StdComponentCategoryMgr, nil,
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, ICatInformation, CatInfo));

    catInfo.EnumClassesOfCategories(1, @CATID_Control, 0, @GUID_NULL, EnumGUID);
    while enumGuid.Next(1, ClassID, Fetched) = S_OK do
    begin
        OleCheck(OleRegGetUserType(ClassID, USERCLASSTYPE_FULL, Name));
        List.Add(Name);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: You are not supposed to post answers with links to duplicates. You are supposed to vote to close as exact duplicate!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much a direct port of the [PowerShell solution from Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660319/where-can-i-find-all-of-the-com-objects-that-can-be-created-in-powershell):

```
procedure GetActiveXObjects( strings : TStrings );
const
    BASE_KEY = '\Software\Classes';
var
    reg : TRegistry;
    keys : TStrings;
    regex : TPerlRegEx;
    key : String;
begin
strings.Clear;
keys := nil;
regex := nil;
reg := TRegistry.Create;
try
    reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    reg.OpenKeyReadOnly( BASE_KEY );

    keys := TStringList.Create;
    reg.GetKeyNames( keys );

    regex := TPerlRegEx.Create;
    regex.RegEx := '^\w+\.\w+$';

    for key in keys do
        begin
        regex.Subject := key;
        if regex.Match and reg.KeyExists( BASE_KEY + '\' + key + '\CLSID' ) then
            strings.Add( key )
        end;

finally
    reg.Free;
    keys.Free;
    regex.Free;
    end;
end;
```